# update.packages fails to update existing packages built for old version of R

Tags: r, installation, package, upgrade

After upgrading R from 3.6.2 to 4.0.1, I used `update.packages(pkgs, checkBuilt=T, ask=F)` command to update existing packages to the new version.  While I expected the command to build/install existing packages for R 4.0.1, the command did not rebuild existing packages that were built/installed for R 3.6.2 and were available for R 4.0.1.  However, I was able to use `install.packages` command to build/install existing packages for R 4.0.1; see [here](https://medium.com/@rvprasad/updating-existing-r-packages-to-new-version-of-r-d21628ee5648) for my current solution.  Have others encountered this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I'm not sure you can use `checkBuilt = T` to update some packages built for older major releases of R. I wiped my R library and installed everything I needed again.

Comment: [R documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/update.packages) says "**checkBuilt** If TRUE, a package built under an earlier major.minor version of R (e.g., 3.4) is considered to be ‘old’."  Hence, my expectation.  I suppose I am reinstalling with `install.packages` but on on top of existing packages (without wiping them).